# How to reference another property in your mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

If I have a property in my schema that depends on another one (like it's minimum value), how do define that in my schema?

I have an endDate and an actualEndDate properties in my schema, the second one will always be greater than or equal to the first one, how do I put that in my schema

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  endDate: {
    type: Date,
    min: new Date(),
    required: true
  },
  actualEndDate: {
    type: Date,
    min: new Date(),  // I need this to be min: this.endDate or something
  }
});
```

Comment: Not being rude this seems quite unfair, I provided you with exactly what you needed and the marked answer is not quite what you wanted, I wonder why is that.

Comment: im sorry im new to asking questions on stackoverflow and I thought I marked both answers (because both satisfy my need) and it turns out I can only mark one and the second one did overwrite your mark ... yesyour solution is the actual one I used in my code and i'll give it back the mark .. sorry again

Comment: It happens, I am just starting out on StackOverflow and quickly hoping to get as many points possible, hence the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before you save/update any document you can add pre-save hooks that can check the validity of document and throw error or update some value based on your logic.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre

Answer (score 2):

**You can add your own custom validation.**

Try this:

```
endDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    // min: new Date()
    // default: Date.now
},
actualEndDate: {
    type: Date,
    validate: [
        function (value) {
            return this.endDate <= value;
        }
    ]
},
```